# Nginx unknown limit_req_zone

Tags: nginx

Nginx currently will not start due to the error mentioned in the title. Here's the actual error I'm getting:

```
$ sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart
Restarting nginx: nginx: [emerg] unknown limit_req_zone "one" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/www.myhashimotosthyroiditis.com:15
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

And this is immediately following creating the VM in question (www.myhashimotosthyroiditis.com), using a template [I found here](http://kbeezie.com/view/nginx-configuration-examples/) that was supposedly the "out-of-the-box-for-lazy-people" templates.

I'm very new to Nginx and I could not find any helpful information via google or searching here, so I beg my pardon if this is a product of stupidity.

Here is the entirety of the VM file:

```
server {
        listen 80;

        server_name myhashimotosthyroiditis.com www.myhashimotosthyroiditis.com;

        root /var/www/myhashimotosthyroiditis;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/myhashimotosthyroiditis.access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/myhashimotosthyroiditis.error.log;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        }

        location /search { limit_req zone=one burst=3 nodelay; rewrite ^ /index.php; }

        fastcgi_intercept_errors off;

        location ~* \.(?:ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
                expires max;
                add_header Pragma public;
                add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        }

        include php.conf;

        # You may want to remove the robots line from drop to use a virtual robots.txt
        # or create a drop_wp.conf tailored to the needs of the wordpress configuration
        include drop.conf;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't defined the [`limit_req_zone`](http://nginx.org/r/limit_req_zone) in `http{}` block.

Comment: That was it. in the /etc/nginx/nginx.conf file. Thanks!